# Dataframe from numpy array without data becoming the index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an array created from a dataframe using .value_counts() which appears as

```
7     600
6     522
8     358
1     336
5     323
11    319
4     316
10    299
12    294
9     278
3     233
2     232
Name: Month, dtype: int64
```

When I do the following the resultant dataframe has the first column as the index rather than a column of data.

```
month_count= pd.DataFrame(month_count)
```

How do I make this two columns of data that I can add headers to?

Comment: `value_counts` returns a series. The dup I'm marking this explains how to convert to a dataframe with columns as required.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was a series so did not realise I'd posted a duplicate question.

Comment: That's OK, easily done :). Your question is still useful for us since the next person who uses the same wording can come here and follow the duplicate link. Thanks!